# how to get the data type of each row in a column

Tags: sql-server

I need to know the datatype of eachrow in a column.

Source:

[image]

output:

[image]

Thanks In Advance

Comment: You mean the data type of each column in a table, it will be the same for all rows.

Comment: Rows don't have data types, columns do. **Every** value in a single column all have the same data type. For your data, in a SQL table, every value would be an `(n)(var)char`.

Comment: Interesting, because I didn't vote this as a dupe, but as unclear, it makes it *look* like I voted it as a dupe but doesn't put my gold badge next to it (as that only happens when I dupe). That looks.... Odd.

Comment: Clearly the column is a string, but it looks like OP is looking to determine/refine the type. The dupe link is not appropriate.

Comment: I don't disagree that it's not a dupe, @JohnCappelletti, (and why I explicitly stated I didn't dupe vote) but I disagree with the reopen. It's as clear as mud. "Data types" of a row make no sense; a row doesn't have a data type a *column* does. And, of the "data types" they've listed, only `numeric` is an actual data type.

Comment: Reading the *textual content* of the question, it sounds like the OP is clearly asking for X when in fact they mean Y - the question probably should not have any answers but more questions to seek clarification rather than relying on graphical representations of data - which I confess I did not look at when they were links, nor should I need to to understand the question.

Comment: Certainly a lazy question and poor phrasing, but the intent seemed very clear to me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `try_convert()` in concert with a `CASE` (or two)

```
Declare @YourTable Table ([column] varchar(50))
Insert Into @YourTable Values 
 ('Abc')
,('123')
,('Adc123')
,('456')
,('45adb')
,('25.25')
 
Select *
      ,[output]  = case when try_convert(money,[column]) is null 
                        then 'alpha' + case when patindex('%[0-9]%',[column])>0 then 'numeric' else '' end
                        else 'numeric' end
 From @YourTable
```

**Results**

```
column  output
Abc     alpha
123     numeric
Adc123  alphanumeric
456     numeric
45adb   alphanumeric
25.25   numeric
```

**Note:**  I use `money` because it tends to be a little more forgiving.

Comment: How can i write the same query  without Patindex ?

Answer (score -1):

```
SELECT *
FROM   INFORMATION_SCHEMA.COLUMNS
WHERE  TABLE_SCHEMA = 'MySchema' -- default is dbo
  AND  TABLE_NAME = 'MyTable'
```